# Spring Boot + JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot

Добрый день. Есть у меня Spring Boot проект с `@RestController` и `@Controller`. При переходе по URL, относящемуся к REST - приходит в ответ json, как положено, а вот индексная страница при переходе по URL `@Controller` не грузится 404 ошибка. Да, и вообще, похоже, ресурсы не видны. Пожалуйста подскажите, что делать?) Спасибо)

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/");
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

    return resolver;
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class IndexController {
      public String index(){
        return "index";
  }
```

страницы в папке src/webapp/WEB-INF/pages

Comment: `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")` аннотацию добавить попробуйте к методу `index();`.

Comment: Сделал так: @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        return "index";
    } При загрузке вижу в консоли Hello! Но страница не загружается

Comment: В метод входит, но не знает, что такое "index".

Comment: Возможно с зависимостями какие-то недостатки. Посмотрите тему http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782915/spring-boot-jsp-404 , пожалуйста.

Comment: @DimXenon это я понял. Вопрос почему?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Нужно в дериктории resources создать папку public положить в нее страницу и убрать все депенденси связаные с Resolver.